# AWS, Rotating SSL/TLS certificates for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As part of, AWS's standard maintenance everyone using RDS should update their SSL/TLS by 2/5/2020. I don't use SSL/TLS keys for my personal project, and I understand we still need to rotate the certs if you do not wish to restart.

*From AWS docs:*

**I don’t use SSL/TLS, can I rotate the certificate without restarting my database?**

```
If you do not want to restart your database, you can use a new CLI option for the modify-db- 
instance CLI command (--no-certificate-rotation-restart) specifically to rotate and stage the 
new certificates on the database host to avoid a restart. However, new certificates will be 
picked up by the database only when a planned or unplanned database restart happens.
```

So I tried command:

```
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier my-instance-1 --ca-certificate-identifier rds-ca-2019 --no-certificate-rotation-restart --region us-east-1
```

This is what I get in output

```
Unknown options: --no-certificate-rotation-restart
```

I Have the latest `awscli`

```
awscli==1.16.314
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check supported options by

> aws rds modify-db-instance help

if `--no-certificate-rotation-restart` not supported, You need to upgrade your AWS CLI

> pip3 install awscli --upgrade

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv1.html